# What is the difference between bind and master.bind in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm in a python class and we are doing some very basic tkinter programs. I was looking up some code examples and many of them use `master.bind` while our textbook only showed us `bind`. I've looked around for a few hours and I can't find any documentation, could someone explain the difference to me?

Comment: The difference has to do with event handling. Here's some documentation about [Levels of binding](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/binding-levels.html) that may help. `bind()` is one of many [Universal widget methods](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html).

Comment: `.bind()` is a method that all Tkinter widgets implement.  `master.bind()` is applying it to a specific widget named `master`.

Comment: Thank you. Both answers were very helpful.

Comment: Your textbook may say only `bind()` but that is likely because the book is assuming you know how to apply a method to a widget. When I tell someone they need to use the `after()` method or `destroy()` method I am assuming they know to do something like `root.after()` or `widget_name.destroy()`. I imagine the book follows the same kind of assumption here.